# in C, Reading a text file into an array of structs then writing a new text file with the array

Tags: c, arrays, file, text, struct

I am fairly new to C and programming in general so I am unsure of my problem. Whenever i run the code and open the new output file, the struct data is only zeros. Here is my code.... I have put the text file contents at the bottom of the question. Thank you in advance.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


typedef struct {
int id;
char description[40];
double mancost;
double sellprice;
} ItemInfo;


int readInfo( ItemInfo input[] );
void listData(ItemInfo input[], int i);

int main(){

ItemInfo input [200];
int i;
i = readInfo( input );
listData (input, i) ;
return 0;
}


int readInfo( ItemInfo input[] ) {
FILE *fin;
int i = 0;

fin = fopen( "C:/Users/ecrooks98/CLionProjects/untitled5/p6-initial.txt", "r" );

if( fin == NULL ) {
    printf( "File cannot be opened\n" );
}
else {
    while( !feof(fin)) {
        fscanf( fin, "%d\t", &input[i].id);
        fscanf( fin, "%39[^\t\n]s\t", input[i].description);
        fscanf( fin, "%lf\t", &input[i].mancost);
        fscanf( fin, "%lf\n", &input[i].sellprice);
        i++;
    }

    fclose( fin );
}

return i;
}
void listData(ItemInfo input [], int i) {
FILE *fout;
int j;

fout = fopen("output.txt", "w");


for (j = 0; j < i; j++) {

        fprintf(fout, "%d\t", input[i].id);
        fprintf(fout, "%s\t", input[i].description);
        fprintf(fout, "%lf\t", input[i].mancost);
        fprintf(fout, "%lf\n", input[i].sellprice);
    }
}
```

My Text file i am inputting also looks like this

```
 2250 shoes 3.00 80.00
 2251 hat .50 20.00
 2252 iphone .10 600.00
 2253 grill 80.00 100.00
```

Comment: Besides the other problems, in your `listData ` function, you need to print `input[j].id` and the rest, not `[i]`.

Answer (score 0):

You should check the return value of `fscanf()` to make sure, that your conversions were successful.

When using the bracket matcher `%39[^\t\n]` the trailing `s` is *not* needed and seen as separate match character. If your input consists just of a single word, it is better to just use `%39s`, otherwise use  `%39[^\t]`.

Furthermore, there is no need to split it into four `fscanf()`-calls, you can make it all in one. And you shouldn't try to match the exact type of blank, a simple space should do the trick. This leads to:

```
int st;

do {
    st = fscanf(fin, "%d %39s %lf %lf ",
                 &input[i].id,
                  input[i].description,
                 &input[i].mancost,
                 &input[i].sellprice);
    i++;
} while (st == 4);
```

This should about do what you need.

Furthermore, as SteveSummit pointed out in the comments, you have to output `input[j].*` in your `listData()`-function, since `j` is the counter variable of your loop (good catch, Steve!).